# How to count index of vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, count

I have 5 int vectors v1 to v5. I want to count the index of the same vectors separately. If a different vector appears in the next vector, it outputs the index of the previous same vectors and starts counting for the new vector.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
std::vector<int>v1={1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int>v2={1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int>v3={1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int>v4={1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int>v5={1, 2, 3};
```

The output should be: vector value = vector of index

```
{1,2,3} = {0,1};
{1,2,3,4} = {2,3};
{1,2,3} = {4};
```

Comment: Why don't you store the vectors in another container, like another vector? Will make it much easier to make it generic.

Comment: And have you tried just *comparing* the vectors? With your current vectors, what happens if you do e.g. `v2 == v1`? What happens if you do `v3 == v2`? (Note the order of the variables in my examples, it could give you a hint about doing the comparisons if you store the vectors in a vector)

Comment: hint: `map<vector<int>, vector<int>>`? (I *suspect* that you can use a vector as a map key, but I'm not actually sure)

Comment: @user253751 yes you can. `std::vector` has `operator<` if the elements have one

Comment: how do you want to use this index? It is just a counter or do you want to use it later to retrieve the vector?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, I want to find which vector appears the most and in which index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to just search the collection of vectors and find in which positions are the elements that match your criterion? Then maybe like this:

```
    std::vector<int> v1={1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v2={1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v3={1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> v4={1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> v5={1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> collection({v1, v2, v3, v4, v5});
    auto found = std::find(collection.begin(), collection.end(), v1);
    while (found != collection.end())
    {
        std::cout << "found at idx = " << std::distance(collection.begin(), found) << std::endl;
        // begin next search after previously found element
        found = std::find(++found, collection.end(), v1);
    }
```

Can be also with custom predicate if you prefer.